# Typed in --watch the wrong file in Sass - Now I get Errno:: ENOENT

Tags: html, css, sass

Earlier I typed in

```
sass --watch style.scs
```

instead of  **style.scss**

Now in my project I have

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - style.scs
```

Even though I've used [CTRL]+C to stop the process and refreshed my browser's cache my local project is still showing the ENOENT error.

Thank you!

Comment: have you run grunt again after that?

Comment: I don't think I even use grunt. when I installed Sass I just used "gem install sass"

Comment: Then have you typed again `sass --watch style.scss` after terminating the process?

Comment: Yes I have done that!

Comment: Try to remove the `sass-cache` `rm .sass-cache/ -R`

Comment: when i type in "rm .sass-cache/ -R" I get rm is not recognized as an internal or external command. when i type in "sass rm .sass-cache/ -R" i get "OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: -R"

Comment: just `delete` the `.sass-cache` folder inside your project. Also, what OS do you have and where do you type to commands in?

Comment: Deleting the .sass-cache folder did nothing. I am on Windows 7 and typing my commands in cmd.exe

Answer (score -1):

I simply watched style.scss for changes using

```
sass --watch style.scss
```

then made one change, saved, and voila!

Comment: This was the first thing I've asked you to do!

Comment: Simply typing sass --watch style.scss didn't fix it. I had to make a change to the file and then save. So it's not the first thing you asked me to do! I hope you didn't down-vote my answer based on this.